# Accessing methods from multiple classes

Tags: java, class, object, methods, invoke

I am working on a program that calculates the cost of flooring based on the dimensions of a room and the type of flooring selected. I have 5 classes (`Cost`, `CustomerInfo`, `OrderSummary`, `MainForm`, and `MainApp`), and the program itself has 3 tabs (Cost, Customer Information, Order Summary).

Each tab is instantiated as its respective object in the `MainForm` class. The problem that I am having is my `OrderSummary` class needs to invoke the `getFloorArea()` and `getTotalCost()` methods from the `Cost` class, and also needs to call the `getCustName()` and `getCustAddress()` methods from the `CustomerInfo` class. Each tab in itself works properly (calculating the area, cost of proposed room / getting the customer's name and address), but I can't figure out how to pull this information into the `OrderSummary` class. The Order Summary tab just shows all of the information as null.

I'm sure that it's because I need to instantiate `Cost` and `CustomerInfo` classes in the `OrderSummary` class, but I can't figure out how to do it. I feel like the problem is 3 different objects are created when I create my tabs, but I don't know how to access the information that is being entered into each tab from the `OrderSummary` class. Any help is really appreciated I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what to do.

I can provide code as needed but it's a pretty long program.

EDIT: Here are some bits that I think will help:

This is in my MainForm, where I create my tabs:

```
    jtp.addTab("Cost", new Cost());
    jtp.addTab("Customer Info", new CustomerInfo());
    jtp.addTab("Order Summary", new OrderSummary());
```

This is method getFloorArea() in class Cost

```
    public double getFloorArea() {

        FloorLength = Double.parseDouble(enterLength.getText());
        FloorWidth = Double.parseDouble(enterWidth.getText());

        FloorArea = FloorLength * FloorWidth;

        return FloorArea;
    }
```

And this is my class OrderSummary, in which I can't figure out how to call these functions in order to display the information:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import helpers.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OrderSummary extends JPanel {

    JTextArea orderSummary;

    public OrderSummary() {
        createPanel();
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        super.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();

        bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        bag.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

        bag.gridx = 0;
        bag.gridy = 0;
        orderSummary = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        orderSummary.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        orderSummary.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.add(orderSummary, bag);

//This is my trouble area, I can't figure out how to access the classes to display the information in this JTextArea        
orderSummary.setText("Customer Name: " +   CustomerInfo.getFirstName() + " " + CustomerInfo.getLastName() +
            "\nAddress: " + CustomerInfo.getStreet() + "\n" + CustomerInfo.getCity() + "\n" + CustomerInfo.getCustState() + "\n" + CustomerInfo.getZip() +
            "\n\nTotal Area: " + Cost.getFloorArea() + " square feet" + 
            "\nCost: " + OutputHelpers.formattedCurrency(Cost.getTotalCost()));
    }

}
```

I've tried making the variables and methods static in the Cost class, but then the calculations and cost do not work within that tab itself. For example, my clear button will clear all variables except the static ones.

Comment: Impossible to answer accurately without some code. Just post the **relevant** parts of your code to help us to help, although it seems to be a classical problem that can be solved by classical patterns such as MVC.

Comment: Could you clarify two things?  1) When you say '3 Tabs' you are talking about user interface code (e.g. JFrame/JTabbedPane) correct?   2)  Can you clarify what the 'MainForm' class does?

Comment: 1) Yes there are 3 JTabbedPanes. 2) The MainForm class creates the frame for the entire GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `Cost` and `CustomerInformation` objects to the `OrderSummary` when you create them in the `MainForm` class. Although you may want to think about remodelling your project.

```
public class MainForm {

    public void myMethod() {
        Cost cost = new Cost();
        CustomerInfo custInfo = new CustomerInfo();
        OrderSummary orderSummary = new OrderSummary(cost, custInfo); 

        jtp.addTab("Cost", cost);
        jtp.addTab("Customer Info", custInfo);
        jtp.addTab("Order Summary", orderSummary);

        ...
    }
}
```

And something like...

```
public class OrderSummary {

    private Cost cost;
    private CustomerInformation custInfo;

    public OrderSummary(Cost cost, CustomerInformation custInfo) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.custInfo = custInfo;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a workaround - the problem is that there's no `Order` class, of which everything would be a child. Each window is getting its own data. To stitch it together, have a the windows know about a hierarchy of objects, of which Order looks like a good parent. Gary's suggestion of OrderSummary would work just as well.